# Standard output redirected to file shows different from actual

Tags: python, shell, io

In my below program, the output is redirected to file test1.txt, but when I open the file, I have three problems here :

1. I see the commands like ls, pwd are below the prompt (sw0:FID128:root>).
2. the prompt is expected to show "sw0:FID128:root>" but it shows "sw0:FID128:root"
3. if the actual output is having 2 tabs, the file shows only 1 tab.

I basically want it to compare with the another file , so it will fail if number of tabs are different.

```
 telconn=pexpect.spawn('telnet 10.24.12.109')
 telconn.logfile = sys.stdout
 telconn.expect(":")
 telconn.send("user" + "\r")
 telconn.expect(":")
 telconn.send("pass" + "\r\r\r\r\n\n\n")
 telconn.expect("key to proceed.")
 telconn.send ("\003")
 telconn.expect("root>")
 prev_std= sys.stdout
 sys.stdout=open("test1.txt","w")

 print "Telnet connection is done"

 telconn.sendline('\n');
 telconn.expect (['>',pexpect.EOF])
 ls = telconn.before

 telconn.sendline('ls -al');
 telconn.expect (['>',pexpect.EOF])
 ls = telconn.before

 telconn.sendline('pwd');
 telconn.expect (['>',pexpect.EOF])
 pwd = telconn.before

 telconn.sendline('noscli');
 telconn.expect (['#',pexpect.EOF])
 nos = telconn.before

 telconn.sendline('terminal length 0');
 telconn.expect (['#',pexpect.EOF])
 term = telconn.before

 telconn.sendline('\n\n');

 telconn .sendline('exit');
 telconn.close()

 print ls
 print pwd
 print nos
 print term

 #print "Ended session"


 sys.stdout.close()
 sys.stdout =prev_std

 fo = open("test1.txt", "r+")
 str = fo.read();
 print "Read String is : ", str
 # Close opend file
 fo.close()
```

Sample output looks like this

```
Telnet connection is done
 ^M
sw0:FID128:root
 ls -al^M
total 32^M
pwddrwx------  3 root root 4096 Feb  2 11:07 ./^M
^M
drwxr-xr-x 28 root root 4096 Feb  3 05:58 ../^M
-rw-r--r--  1 root sys   507 Feb  1 06:47 .bash_logout^M
-rw-r--r--  1 root sys    27 Feb  1 06:47 .inputrc^M
-rw-r--r--  1 root sys  1220 Feb  1 06:47 .profile^M
-rw-r--r--  1 root sys  2551 Feb  1 06:47 .rhosts^M
drwxr-xr-x  2 root sys  4096 Feb  1 09:51 .ssh/^M
-rw-r--r--  1 root sys   617 Feb  1 06:47 .toprc^M
-rw-r--r--  1 root root    0 Feb  3 06:01 mcast_trc^M
-rw-r--r--  1 root root    0 Feb  3 06:01 sysdiag_trc^M
sw0:FID128:root
 pwd^M
/root^M
```

Answer (score 0):

> I see the commands like ls, pwd are below the prompt

Your output has inconsistent newlines (`^M` is `CR`). This means that some parts of your ensemble output `CR+LF`, others - just `LF`. It's hard to tell which is which just from the single output. Separate them and see for yourself.

> the prompt is expected to show "sw0:FID128:root>" but it shows
>   "sw0:FID128:root"

Possible reasons:

1. you aren't capturing the output faithfully. E.g. something gets printed to `stderr`, too.

   - use `2>&1` or equivalent or otherwise see both outputs somehow
2. when redirected, the output actually differs from what would be seen on the console. Some programs do this, using the [`isatty()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/isatty) function to tell them apart. The rationale typically is to better fit the output for human or machine reading. Many such programs have switches to explicitly specify the output flavor.

   - you can use something like `| cat` (for output redirection) or `cat <command_file> |` (for input redirection) to check if this is the case

With `telnet`, it can be either. `>` is a command prompt. It's typically printed to `stderr`. It can be still printed there or not printed at all when there's redirection.

> if the actual output is having 2 tabs, the file shows only 1 tab.

Probably the same as 2). Maybe something which the output goes through does tab conversion, too.

Comment: for my 1st point, for example ls -al is passed from sendline and output  total 7736
drwx------  3 root root    4096 Feb  5 05:19 ./
drwxr-xr-x 28 root root    4096 Feb  5 05:30 ../
-rw-r--r--  1 root sys      507 Feb  1 06:47 .bash_logout
-rw-r--r--  1 root sys       27 Feb  1 06:47 .inputrc
-rw-r--r--  1 root sys     1220 Feb  1 06:47 .profile
-rw-r--r--  1 root sys     2551 Feb  1 06:47 .rhosts
drwxr-xr-x  2 root sys     4096 Apr 22  2015 .ssh/
-rw-r--r--  1 root sys      617 Feb  1 06:47 .toprc

Comment: @Suma I can see that already. The lone `LF` is after the prompt. So examine in detail what happens at this point - where is this `LF` coming from.